# How to factorize this code

Tags: c#, asp.net, factorization

I work on a MVC C# project and i have some classes that are always the same. What i would like to do is find a way to factorize the code so that i can implement it rapidly every time I need.

Here is an example of one of those classes

```
public class FeedbackManager
{
   public List<Feedback> List = new List<Feedback>();
   public FeedbackManager(){}
   public List<Feedback> GetAll() { ... }
   public Feedback GetById(string id) { ... }
   public void Edit(string id, Feedback item) { ... }
   public void Delete(string id) { ... }
   public void Add(Feedback item) { ... }
   public void Serialize() { ... }
   public static FeedbackManager DeSerialize() { ... }
}
```

What i tried to do was to create an interface and change all the "Feedback" with "object" so that when I implement the interface I change "object" with "Feedback" but it didn't worked out. If you got some tricks to achieve such factorization i'd be interested

Comment: Are you looking for Generics?  `public class Manager<T>`?  Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: I'm also very unclear on what you want to do.  This also looks like it's a bit more of a generic c# problem you are asking about.  There are several design patterns that could be used, but without more information as to how you want to use the code it's hard to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

```
public interface IManager<T>
{
   public List<T> GetAll();
   public T GetById(string id);
   public void Edit(string id, T item);
   public void Delete(string id);
   public void Add(T item);
   public void Serialize();
}
```

or

```
public abstract class AbstractManager<T>
{
   public List<T> List;

   protected AbstractManager(){
        List = new List<T>();
   }

   public abstract List<T> GetAll();
   public abstract T GetById(string id);
   public abstract void Edit(string id, T item);
   public abstract void Delete(string id);
   public abstract void Add(T item);
   public abstract void Serialize();
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks ! I always wondered what were those "T" keyword. Thanks both of you !

Comment: Not a problem. T can actually be anything, it's just a standard to use it to represent a generic concept. If T will always represent a data entity, you might make T, TEntity instead or TKey if the generic will be used as a key value. See this for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: Since we're playing "correct more" your GetById is returning a concrete type coupling the not-so-abstract class. @TimothyStepanski

Comment: Whoops, didn't pull that out. Good catch.

Answer (score -2):

As per the #1 comment on your answer it sounds exactly like a good use case for generics:

```
public interface IManager<T>
{
   public List<T> List = new List<T>();
   public List<T> GetAll() { ... }
   public T GetById(string id) { ... }
   public void Edit(string id, T item) { ... }
   public void Delete(string id) { ... }
   public void Add(T item) { ... }
   public void Serialize() { ... }
}
```

something along these lines?

Comment: Interfaces can't define fields or static anything.

Comment: Yes thanks ! I always wondered what were those "T" keyword. Thanks both of you !

Comment: removed static as per comment, totally missed it :) glad we have the csc to catch those bad guys, too bad it doesn't run here :)